# how to set Calendar with variable

Tags: java, android

I have a set calendar to set week of month in my aplication.

here is the variable
1.

```
Long date1 = cursor.getLong(12); // first I load a choosen date to a database
//date result is 1365569546000

//then I convert to string
SimpleDateFormat sdfd = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
String day3 = sdfd.format(date1);

SimpleDateFormat sdfm = new SimpleDateFormat("M");
String month3 = sdfm.format(date1);

SimpleDateFormat sdfy = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
String year3 = sdfy.format(date1);

intent.putExtra("days",day3);
intent.putExtra("months",month3);
intent.putExtra("years",year3);
```

2 new activity.

```
Bundle extras2 = getIntent().getExtras();
        dayWeek = extras2.getInt("days");
        monthWeek = extras2.getInt("months");
        yearWeek = extras2.getInt("years");
```

before I use manual insert and it work the result is **2**.

here is the code.

```
Calendar calFr = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Jakarta"));
        calFr.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
        calFr.set(2013, Calendar.APRIL, 10);
int weekOfMonthFr = calFr.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        TextView txtMinggu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.week);
        txtMinggu.setText(""+weekOfMonthFr);
```

,but now I use variable EXTRAS to set the week of month.

here is the code

```
calFr.set(yearWeek, monthWeek, dayWeek);
```

> yearWeek = 2013;
>
> monthWeek = 4;
>
> dayWeek = 10;

but the result is **5**

I want the result is **2**

how to fix that?

Comment: I am sorry but I really don't understand your question, read it twice, thrice but didn't get it. What are you trying to achieve..What is the problem.. What is expected, and what do you  get?

Comment: i try to show week of month calendar. the problem, the week is error when i use variable to set Calendar . the result week of month is 5, not 2. @Pragnani

Comment: very hard to understand question. Use edit option to correct it so that people here can understand. Even your comment don't help.

Comment: @Alexbelek Have checked my answer..?

Answer (score 0):

> Output you have get is right..

because  when you set month `4`  it will take `May`

as the values for the months will starts from 0

Check here [Constant Field Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.MAY)
so

```
January -0
Feb    - 1
Mar    -2
April  -3
May -   4
```

so `May 10th is Friday`, so it will give `5`

Comment: still give `5` maybe something wrong in my Extra variable @Pragnani

Comment: @Alexbelek you are not understanding the answer... set `month 3` to get the required value `2` because `may 10th 2013` is `Friday` and has the week day of `5`. so it is correct change values to `calFr.set(2013, 3, 10);` you will get `2`

Comment: yes i understand the answer. `calFr.set(2013, 3, 10);` the result is `2` but when i put a variable extra in `year` and `day`. there is a error, the result still `5`. but the `year` and `day` value is same. `2013` and `10`

Comment: @Alexbelek `but when i put a variable extra in year and day` I really don't understand what do you mean by that...